# Show file in Windows Explorer using Go?

Tags: windows, go

How do you show a file in windows explorer using Go?

This command works as expected from the command line:

```
explorer /select,C:\data\My File.txt
```

I can't get the same command to work using Go's `exec.Command()` method, no matter what combination of arguments tried.

This works:

```
exec.Command(`explorer`, `/select,C:\data\MyFile.txt`) // SUCCEEDS
```

but fails with a space in the filename.

```
exec.Command(`explorer`, `/select,C:\data\My File.txt`) // FAILS
```

Notes:

- [Explorer command line flag documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457)
- [os/exec Command() documentation.](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get it to work if you separate the `/select,` action and the actual path, and you pass them as separate parameters:

```
exec.Command(`explorer`, `/select,`, `C:\data\My File.txt`)
```

Comment: Thanks Icza! I was pulling my hair out there. :)

Comment: @Shannon That's a good indication that it's time to post on SO :)

Answer (score 8):

A more complete answer for the golang newbies (like myself):

```
package main
import (
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command(`explorer`, `/select,`, `C:\data\My File.txt`)
    cmd.Run()
}
```